# DROP DOWN LIST SENDING ENTITY UNIQUE ID INSTEAD OF SELECTED ITEM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm populating a drop down list in my view with items sent from a view.bag populated from my db. In the view everything is fine, but when it saves to the database its passing along the unique ID for that entity instead of the selected value.. Can someone please help.. 
Thank You...

*note my static populated dropdown works... Its the dropdown from the database thats causing the proplem.

Heres my code:

```
 Controller:

 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TeacherID = new SelectList(db.Teachers, "TeacherID", "LastName");
        ViewBag.SemesterID = new SelectList(db.Semesters, "SemesterID",            
        SemesterName");
        ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.Courses, "Section", "CourseSection");
        ViewBag.RoomID = new SelectList(db.Rooms, "RoomID", "FacilityIdentifier");


        var meetlist = new SelectList(new[]
               {
                 new { ID="M", Name="M"},
                 new { ID="T", Name="T"},
                 new { ID="W", Name="W"},
                 new { ID="TH", Name="TH"},
                 new { ID="T", Name="T"},
                 new { ID="F", Name="F"},
                 new { ID="MW", Name="MW"},  
                 new { ID="TTH", Name="TTH"}, 
               },
"ID", "Name", 1);

        ViewData["meetlist"] = meetlist

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Assignment</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
         COURSE
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CourseSection", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Course.Section)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("TeacherID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherID)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("RoomID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomID)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SemesterID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("RoomID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomID)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollCap)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollCap)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollCap)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollTotal)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollTotal)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollTotal)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Meeting)
    </div>
        <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.Meeting, ViewData["meetlist"] as SelectList,
                new { style = "width: 200px"})

               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=>u.Meeting)
       </div> 

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

and model:

```
public class Assignment
{
    public int AssignmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public int SemesterID { get; set; }


    public int EnrollCap { get; set; }
    public int EnrollTotal { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Meeting { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Room { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Semester> Semester { get; set; }

}
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply appropriate `SelectList` (through ViewBags in your case) as datasource to dropdowns like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseSection", (SelectList)ViewBag.CourseID)
@Html.DropDownList("TeacherID", (SelectList)ViewBag.TeacherID )
```

and so on...

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply.. No its still not working.. The funny thing is that the same logic I have above works perfect within another controller/view relationship. Thanks again

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (with both bindings: explicit and mvc convention based). I can't get your statement "..its passing along the unique ID for that entity instead of the selected value". Its now up to your db-insertion logic. Can you show POST version of Create()?

Comment: @Bishnu... It was a dumb mistake on my part.. I spent half a day to find out in my view, I was actually calling the Id value instead of the field value i wanted.. But thanks a million..